# How to efficiently build a tree from a tree structure

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a bunch of objects in a tree structure. but currently this structure doesn't work for me, because I need to use v-teeview, so I need to restructure it....

my tree structure currently is like:

```js
items: [
  {
    data: [
      { ... },
    ],
    children: [],
  },
  {
    data: [{ ... }],
    children: [{...}, {...}]
   }
]
```

and I I need to restructure something like:

```js
  items: [
      {     
         id: 76,
         name: "ADIS ",
         children: [],
      },
      {
        id: 64,
        name: "YSVERIS",
        children: [
          {
            id: 85,
            name: "MERCEDES",
            children: [],
          },
          {
            id: 83,
            name: "YNGRIBEL",  
            children: [],
          },
        ],
      }
    ]
```

so, I implemented one function recursive, this function is for restructure the tree.

[code in codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/wispy-microservice-l8vvl?file=/src/App.vue):

```js
export default {
  methods: {
    createTree(items) {
      items.forEach((element) => {
        if (element.children.length === 0) {
          this.datatree.push({
            id: element.data[0].id,
            name: element.data[0].name,
            children: [],
          });
        } else {
          this.datatree.push({
            id: element.data[0].id,
            name: element.data[0].name,
            children: this.createTree(element.children),
          });
        }
      });
      console.log("root: ", this.datatree);
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.createTree(this.items);
  },
}
```

so my current problem is that when I built the new tree, its children are undefined, what I'm doing wrong?

In my example code I'm using console.log(), to see the new tree

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`createTree()` returns nothing, so assigning the return value to `children` would just make `children` have an `undefined` value.

One solution is to recursively call a helper method (e.g., named "`createNode`") that creates the tree nodes from each array element (instead of recursively calling `createTree()`). Return the result from `createTree()`, and assign the return value to `datatree`:

```js
function createTree(items) {
  const createNode = ({ data, children }) => ({
    ...data[0],
    children: children?.map(child => createNode(child))
  })
  return items.map(item => createNode(item))
}

// MyComponent.vue
export default {
  mounted() {
    this.datatree = createTree(this.items)
  }
}
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-create-tree-from-array?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FMyList.vue)